# Why are iframes so slow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, iframe

I have little bit longer question for you - but hope answer will be very simple :)

Let's say I have very simple page with link and iframe (just for simple example).

```
<body>
    <a href="test.html" target="mframe">open link></a>
    <iframe name="mframe" [params] />
</body>
```

So when you click on the link it will load test.html in the frame.

Now I will change the iframe with div and ajax call.

```
<body>
    <a href="doAjaxCall('test.html')">open link</a>
    <div id="main-content"></div>
</body>
```

The doAjaxCall will simply use GET ajax requset to get whole response, parse it (using JavaScript) and grab content in <body> tag and put it into main-content.innerHTML.

test.html contains a lot of html, also css styles (but the same as are on parent page - so I don't need them when I'm using ajax solution).

**Question:**

Why is this ajax solution SO faster? I'm still downloading the same amount of data (downloading whole test.html).

Why is the iframe solution so slow? Is it because of browser have to parse all possible styles again? Or is there any other overhead of iframes?

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour in more than one browser?

Comment: Actually my example was very simple. :)

In real I was trying this solution on one bigger site where we are using iframes now. I've removed them and replace them with that ajax solution. As I wrote, I just replaced links with ajax calls, but traffic is still the same.

And yes, it is definitely faster in every browser (IE/FF/CH/SAF).

Only reason I can see now is that browser does not need to load styles again and again just replace innerHTML of 'main-content' div.

Thanks!

Pavol.

Comment: If your stylesheet is in a dedicated css file called via the link tag, then the browser should take advantage of caching and only load it once. btw I am curious how much slower your iframe is - we're talking milliseconds, right?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You are pretty much on the right track. iframes are going to be slower because there is an additional overhead for the browser (rendering it, maintaining it's instance and references to it).

The ajax call is going to be a bit faster because you get the data in and you then inject it, or do whatever you want with it. The iframe will need to build an entirely new "page" in the browsers memory, and then place it in the page.

Comment: 6 years later, is this still an accurate assessment?

Comment: @donohoe yes, it's still the same situation even 7 years later

Comment: a further 3 years later and still applies, i believe.

Comment: one more year and still same

Comment: ...and one more

Comment: ..2022 is still same...

Comment: just checked, this is still the case

Comment: does Chrome down prioritizes javascript that is running inside iframe compared to JS running directly on the page ?

Answer (score 18):

Steve Souders has a post [*Using Iframes Sparingly*](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/03/using-iframes-sparingly/) on his High Performance Web Sites blog that may provide some more insight.

Answer (score 0):

Although the browsers have improved since 2009, the fact that the browser needs to hit additional servers (assuming the iframes are for thrid-party content), or hit the local server again (assuming the iframes are for local content), this would still impact page performance. In general, additional HTTP requests will always have an impact on a page's performance. If it's possible to build the iframe after the page is loaded and than render the iframe's content, this would improve the initial page load. However, I think this would impact the pages performance while the iframe loads the additional content.