# How to speed up wordpress website with iframe included?

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe

I made website: https://flugradar24.live/ and I had to add iframe with fly radar on it. But when I added it, my website is very slow. How to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are iframes so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092071/why-are-iframes-so-slow)

Comment: Go through this link - https://colorlib.com/wp/how-to-speed-up-wordpress-site/ - for speed up the wordpress site